# How to change my react webpage according to the button I am pressing on a static webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, conditional-rendering

I am basically creating an online game .I have set up an Express server which till now served static webpages . Now , I have  static webpage which has two buttons 'Create Game' and 'Join Game'. Now, when I press either of the buttons, I get the same webpage which allows my players to choose their respective colors. What I am looking for is when I press the Create Game button , I need to get a Start Game Button but the Start Game button shouldn't be present when I press the Join Game Button. How do I achieve this?

Here is the github link: https://github.com/Metronome03/Dots-and-Boxes-Online

I tried to use readFile to read the react webpage and using replace to change a placeholder tag but that didn't work as expected. I tried to place another express application endpoint to send a script which would then setup the button but that didn't allow me to send the script no matter what I did

Comment: Give reproducible code you can use [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) with pre-installed React v18, instead of GitHub link

Comment: (Your GitHub anyways consists of only README, you haven't pushed anything.)

Comment: Please check other branches